# Robot frame work >> jquery >> Execute Javascript command

Tags: javascript, jquery, command, robotframework

I am using robot frame work, I have to get some grid content using jquery. I have used "Execute Javascript" command. But it is not recognizing any jquery commands like document. or window. I am using selenium 2. I have googled for last two days found no relevant answers. Please tell me if we have to give any new libraries or download selenium1 library instead of selenium2.

> ERROR:
>   javascript                                                                             | FAIL |
>   WebDriverException: Message: u"unknown error: Object [object global] has no method 'getElementById'\n  (Session info: chrome=32.0.1700.107)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)"

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far. If anyway possible provide us a small example which demonstrates the problem so we can run it ourselves.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of getElementById try using $('#elementid')

Comment: Hi MACMAN.. similar to elementid I want to use class. I tried with $('@classname') and also with $('.classname'). I have even tried using tagnanme along with classname. Can you please tell me how to fetch content by using class instead of element.

Comment: Look at the console to see if it generates any error. The error description will tell you exactly where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript

> Note that, by default, the code will be executed in the context of the
>   Selenium object itself, so this will refer to the Selenium object. Use
>   window to refer to the window of your application, e.g.
>   window.document.getElementById('foo').

Comment: hello Harri.. that is how i gave the command. if we press ctrl space the same text is present. however thanks for answer

Comment: hi harri,

I have used the command window.document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML. It is working but 
i) I want to get the text of that object. how do I do that? (.text() is not working)
ii) I have used window.document.getElementByClassName('foo') and I am able to get the object. Now I want the text from this. Please tell me some suggestion here.

Hope to see answer.